# URL has problems in laravel app wihile using S3 on local machine

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

Imagine you've uploaded a file on a S3 bucket or any type of external storage, right? the address might be :

```
storage.mystie.com/file
```

and the browser sees this like:

```
https://storage.mysite.com/file
```

but the app I'm working on, sends it like this:

```
//https://storage.mysite.com
```

and it results in this error:

```
Error executing "ListObjects" on "//https://IP"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host:
```

What's my problem? is it related to my `.env` file?!

Comment: Can you add your code and explain more?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. The code is under an NDA and I can't share it.

Comment: can you please if you have added extra `//` in your code or in `.env`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented "AWS S3" in one of my Laravel's project when I'm going to save user data and upload his profile picture on s3 storage, while updating that image unlink the previous one and then upload the newest picture.

While storing User's Information code was like-this:

```
$user = User::create([
    'first_name' => preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', ucfirst($user['first_name'])),
    'last_name' => preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', ucfirst($user['last_name'])),
    'email' => strtolower($user['email']),
    'phone' => $user['phone'],
    'address' => $user['address'],
    'avatar' => $this->avatar?env('s3').Storage::disk('s3')->put('/profile',$this->avatar,'public'):'',
    'type' => 'business',
    'password' => bcrypt('business123456789'),
    'meta' => $user['meta']

]);
```

While updating User's Data:

```
$filne_name = $this->old_avatar;
if($_FILES['avatar']['size'] > 0 && env('image-upload') == 'true')
{
    if(!empty($this->old_avatar))
    {
        $image = pathinfo($this->old_avatar);
        $response = Storage::disk('s3')->exists('/profile/'.$image['basename']);
        if($response)
        {
          Storage::disk('s3')->delete('/profile/'.$image['basename']);
        }
    }
    $filne_name = env('s3').Storage::disk('s3')->put('/profile',$this->avatar,'public');
}
return  User::where('id',$this->segment(3))->update([
    'first_name' =>  preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', ucfirst($user['first_name'])),
    'last_name' => preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', ucfirst($user['last_name'])),
    'email'     => $user['email'],
    'phone' => $user['phone'],
    'address' => $user['address'],
    'avatar' => $filne_name,
    'meta' => json_encode($user['meta'])

]);
```

And in my .env
s3='https://bucket_link.com/' (That was s3 bucket link)